# Get size of single pages in a multi-page pdf document in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, pdf, size

I am writing an app in objective-c that splits multi-page pdf files into several files.
In order to control the size of the resulting split files I am looking for a way to progammatically get the size of the single pages in the multi-page pdf file. Could not find anything in the APIs. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such information in iOS/OS X PDF related APIs. Due to the structure of PDF files computing the size a PDF page occupies on disk is quite complicated. Also because pages can share resources, the sum of separate page sizes will not equal the size of the final file.